# Kivy Button Is Too Much Sensitive and responds to any click on Screen

Tags: python, kivy

I am beginning with kivy and has created a simple program, the program has 1 button, 1 label and 1 textinput.
When the problem is launched the kivy button starts automatically responding to all calls over the app.
It makes the app pathetic, as doing anything triggers the button.
Can anyone help me with this on how i can limit my button to respond only its touched and to remain stale to any other events. I searched a lot across google and tutorials but couldnt find anything useful.

Trying to make button as it should be to respond only when its clicked and to not respond to any events outside its area.

Comment: Can you share what code you have written so far?

Comment: ok, i will share it

Comment: https://git.launchpad.net/gatimaan/tree/main.py?h=main (main.py)

Comment: https://git.launchpad.net/gatimaan/tree/gatimaan.kv?h=main (kv file)

Comment: I have now added a if clause although sometimes the app still triggers the button automatically.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.